# iOS - Comparing NSDate with another NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

i know how to get difference between two NSDate as follow

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:anyPreviousDate];
```

and i know it will return me `NSTimeInterval` in positive seconds. what I want to know is what it will return if my `anyPreviousDate` is greater than `[NSDate date]` i.e. `anyPreviousDate` has not been passed it will come in future.

just curious if anybody has done that before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the doc : The interval between the receiver and the anotherDate parameter. If the receiver is earlier than anotherDate, the return value is negative. If anotherDate is nil, the results are undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found another very nice approach to do the same...
here is the code, i thought to share it with stackoverflow.
[Cocoa has couple of methods for this](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-DontLinkElementID_6):

in NSDate

```
– isEqualToDate:  
– earlierDate:  
– laterDate:  
– compare:
```

When you use `- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate` ,you get back one of these:

```
The receiver and anotherDate are exactly equal to each other, NSOrderedSame
The receiver is later in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedDescending
The receiver is earlier in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedAscending.
```

example:

```
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
NSDate * mile = [[NSDate alloc] initWithString:@"2001-03-24 10:45:32 +0600"];
NSComparisonResult result = [now compare:mile];

NSLog(@"%@", now);
NSLog(@"%@", mile);

switch (result)
{
    case NSOrderedAscending: NSLog(@"%@ is in future from %@", mile, now); break;
    case NSOrderedDescending: NSLog(@"%@ is in past from %@", mile, now); break;
    case NSOrderedSame: NSLog(@"%@ is the same as %@", mile, now); break;
    default: NSLog(@"erorr dates %@, %@", mile, now); break;
}

[mile release];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   if([previousDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedDescending){
    // Previous date is greater than current date.i.e. previous date 
    //is still to come 
   }else{
   //Previous date is smaller then current date.i.e. previous date
   //has passed.
   }
```

compare method of NSDate object returns NSComparisonResult, which is an enum.

NSComparisonResult has following values.

NSOrderedSame is returned if left and right operands are equal

NSOrderedAscending is returned if left operand is smaller than the right operand

NSOrderedDescending is returned if ft operand is greater than the right operand

Answer (score 0):

If anyPreviousDate is actually ten seconds in the future, then your code will return -10.0. It happens quite often that you define NSDates that are some time in the future (for example to do something one minute from now), so this isn't unusual at all.

Answer (score 0):

[this's a screenshot to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fngJm.png)

```
         NSDate * savedDate = [recordsDic[record.transactionId] modifiedDate];
         NSDate * newDate = record.modifiedDate;
         NSComparisonResult comparisonResult = [newDate compare:savedDate];
         NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [newDate timeIntervalSinceDate:savedDate];
         NSLog(@"\nsavedDate: %@   \nnewDate  : %@  \n===> timeInterval: %f",savedDate,newDate,timeInterval);
         if (comparisonResult == NSOrderedSame) {
             NSLog(@"they are same!!!!");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"they are NOT same!!!!");
         }
```

```
Console log:
2019-04-11 17:26:47.903059+0800 xxxxx[19268:24419134] 
savedDate: Thu Apr 11 15:47:23 2019   
newDate  : Thu Apr 11 15:47:23 2019  
===> timeInterval: 0.000365
2019-04-11 17:26:47.903193+0800 xxxxx[19268:24419134] they are NOT same!!!!
```

Can you believe this!? but That's true, I spent almost a whole day figuring this out. cause this won't consistently happen!!!
so I strongly recommend:
1. Do NOT use instance method "- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)other;" to compare, you would see something really wired and you can not figure out. 
2. timeIntervalSinceDate is more precise.